# JSON result formatting error

Tags: php, arrays, json, function, escaping

My JSON Value is like this -

```
$arr2 = array('dn'=>'NR/2014/02/1257','dd'=>'1393934346');
$arr=array('id'=>'123456','fname'=>'ABC','lname'=>'XYZ','dt'=>array($arr2));
$json = json_encode($arr));
```

RESULT -

```
{
  "id":"123456","fname":"ABC","lname":"XYZ",
  "dt":[
          {"dn":"NR\/2014\/02\/1257","dd":1393934346}
       ]
}
```

In which `dn` value is `NR\/2014\/02\/1257` but I want the `dn` value to be `NR/2014/02/1257` as per my real `dn` value.

Can anybody help me???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make use of the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` as a parameter to ur `json_encode()` function.  Available since PHP 5.4.0.

```
<?php
$arr2 = array('dn'=>'NR/2014/02/1257','dd'=>'1393934346');
$arr=array('id'=>'123456','fname'=>'ABC','lname'=>'XYZ','dt'=>array($arr2));

echo $json = json_encode($arr,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

**`OUTPUT :`**

```
{"id":"123456","fname":"ABC","lname":"XYZ","dt":[{"dn":"NR/2014/02/1257","dd":"1393934346"}]}
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/110413)

---

**Turnaround for PHP versions less than 5.4.0**, that doesn't support `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` , Doing a simple replace of backslashes does the job.

```
echo $json = str_replace('\\','',json_encode($arr));
```

Comment: thanks for your help but when i use JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES with json encode method, its not working... why???

Comment: Check out the demo in the answer it works as per your expectations. Btw which version of PHP are you using ?

Comment: Simply do a replace , `echo $json = str_replace('\\','',json_encode($arr));` because `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` works on versions above >= 5.4

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` parameter when using `json_encode()` function (PHP version have to >= 5.4).

But the string `"NR\/2014\/02\/1257"` is exactly same with `"NR/2014/02/1257"`, so the `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` is not necessary.

```
console.log("NR\/2014\/02\/1257" === "NR/2014/02/1257"); //true
```

**But if you put the json string inside a `<script>` tag, which doesn't allow `</` inside the strings, so it is much safer to escape the `/`.**

Answer (score 1):

```
$json =json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES`

```
$arr2 = array('dn'=>'NR/2014/02/1257','dd'=>'1393934346');
$arr=array('id'=>'123456','fname'=>'ABC','lname'=>'XYZ','dt'=>array($arr2));

$json = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES));
```

It is one of the predefined json constants in php http://www.php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(jsondata);
```